# Accepted the automatic Java update and now can't open Eclipse,

Tags: java, eclipse, updates

I'm very new to Java and computing in general. Currently taking an intro to programming course revolving around Java.

I got a notification earlier about a Java update when I wasn't using it and accepted it without much thought. I just now tried to open Eclipse to start doing some homework and when I did, all I got was the following message:

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin

I have no idea where to go from here. I can't get in touch with my web developer friend helped me set up Java on my computer originally, and my instructor isn't responding to emails. I've tried to fix things like this myself in the past and have only compounded the problem, so I'm reluctant to try anything I'm not certain about, which is to say I'm reluctant to try anything at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check to see if you can find the java at c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\ location. When u find where java is installed go to the location where your eclipse is installed and open the file eclipse.ini in a text editor and check the part where you have -vm. There you might have configured an installation of java

Answer (score 0):

First, try to find where your jdk locates. If you don't remember where you have installed it, try to search for jdk or jre folder in *C:/Programm Files*. Then go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's tab in Eclipse and set path to your jdk or jre.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out from an old question- just had to change the text to the updated JRE in the Eclipse initializer. Thank you for your help!